# Bash, how to globally fix ^H and ^? backspace problems

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, bashrc

I'd like to fix this frequent problem where the shell on a remote server thinks my terminal's backspace key is `^?` and sometimes it thinks it is `^H`, and happens to be incorrect and outputs the wrong character when I press backspace. If I set it to ^H or ^? with `stty erase ^H` or `stty erase ^?` in my .bashrc file, and use some other terminal to access the server, it often ends up wrong. So I'm stuck having to manually type `stty erase [whatever]` to fix it when I notice the backspace key is wrong.

What I'd like to do is bind both `^?` and `^H` to backspace, because if I can do this, I can just add it to all of my .bashrc files, and it will certainly end this nightmare. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 11):

[This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html) has all the information you will ever need on this issue; I suggest you read it. Now, if you are using `bash`, it should be enough to create an `~/.inputrc` file containing these lines:

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
# this is actually equivalent to "\C-?": delete-char
# VT
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line
# kvt
"\e[H":beginning-of-line
"\e[F":end-of-line
# rxvt and konsole (i.e. the KDE-app...)
"\e[7~":beginning-of-line
"\e[8~":end-of-line
```

As an added bonus, they will make <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> work as well.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the information in [https://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/~anne/keyboard/keyboard.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120621035133/http://www.ibb.net/%7Eanne/keyboard/keyboard.html) is indeed what you need. One correction to the information, is of their suggestion (for XTerm):

```
*VT100.Translations: #override \
          <Key>BackSpace: string(0x7F)\n\
          <Key>Delete:    string("\033[3~")\n\
          <Key>Home:      string("\033[1~")\n\
          <Key>End:       string("\033[4~")
*ttyModes: erase ^?
```

While this will get XTerm to send the right character, and change stty to have backspace as `^?`, it will still erroniously report `^H` as backspace under some occasions, breaking i.e. backspace in Vim instert mode (see here: https://bugs.gentoo.org/154090). To avoid this, use `VT100.backarrowKey: false` instead, so:

```
*VT100.backarrowKey: false
*VT100.Translations: #override \
          <Key>Delete:    string("\033[3~")\n\
          <Key>Home:      string("\033[1~")\n\
          <Key>End:       string("\033[4~")
*ttyModes: erase ^?
```

(see also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#Fix_the_backspace_key)

Answer (score 0):

There is probability that you are using not `bash` but `sh` shell.
Check current shell name:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Change user shell to bash:

```
chsh --shell /bin/bash $LOGNAME
```