# Why does my backspace key keep being unbound from erase?

Tags: mingw, git-bash, stty

Every 5 to 20 minutes I need to retype

```
stty erase ^H
```

in the console because my backspace key randomly starts printing ^H instead of deleting characters. This is happening in git bash on a lenovo T410

Any help would be appreciated this is pretty annoying

Comment: Have you tried? "stty erase ^H backspace" already?

Comment: that didn't work, as in it threw an error. When I say I type 'stty erase ^H' I mean I actually hit backspace to generate that '^H' value because all backspace does is print that

Comment: Presumably some program which OP is running changes the stty erase value.

Comment: Duplicate of [Bash, how to globally fix ^H and ^? backspace problems](http://superuser.com/questions/641095/bash-how-to-globally-fix-h-and-backspace-problems) ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to your `~/.inputrc` file (and restart the terminal of course):

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
```

Answer (score 0):

Some console utilities don't interpret the backspace character (^H) as a backspace and need a delete instead.

In this case, enabling the option 'Backspace sends delete' in the 'Mapped Keys' sub-category under 'Emulation' and 'Terminal' in the 'Session Options' should allow for the 'Backspace' key to function correctly without affecting how the command shell works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to `.bash_profile` (or running it from within the terminal) solved the issue for me without needing to change any other parameters:

```
export TERM=xterm
```